# Logarithms question: $6+\log_3 (y) =\log_3(y)^5$

Tags: logarithms

Logarithms question: $6+\log_3 (y) =\log_3(y)^5$

Forms part of a simultaneous equation.

FULL QUESTION:

Solve for $x$ and $y$:
\begin{cases}
\log_3(xy) =5 \\[4px]
\log_3(x)\log_3(y)=6
\end{cases}

Answer (score 5):

Set $u=\log_3x$ and $v=\log_3y$. The system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
u+v=5\\
uv=6
\end{cases}
$$
and the solutions are quite easy to find.

It's quite unclear how you arrive to the title equation.

Answer (score 4):

As we know that $\log_33=1$ 
$\therefore$ $$6\log_33=\log_3(y)^5-\log_3(y)$$ $$\log_3(3)^6=\log_3\left(\frac{y^5}{y}\right)$$ $$\log_3(3)^6=\log_3(y)^4$$ taking antilog both the side we can write as $$3^6=y^4$$ I don't know how did you find that equation but now from the first part of the full question $$\log_3(xy)=5$$ $\implies$ $$3^5=xy$$ put the value of $y$ in this then we get $$x=\frac{3^5}{3^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$ $$x=3^\frac{7}{2}$$

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 0):

Just take $\log_3 (y) =  t $ and $\log_3 (x) =  s $.
 The equations become 
 $$ s + t =5$$
 $$ st = 6 $$
Thus, s,t are the roots of the equation $a^2-5a+6 =0$  whose obvious roots are 2,3.

Therefore, $(y=8,x=27)$ or $(x=8,y=27)$ are the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

First, your "Full Question" is **not** the same as the first equation you post.  Do you intend one of those "=" to be "-"?  Second, is $log_3(y)^5$ untended to be $log(y^5)$?  That would fit your "$5log_3(y)$" in your "Full Question".  If you mean "$6+ log_3(y)= log_3(y^5)$" that is the same as $6+ log_3(y)= 5log_3(x)$ so that $4log_3(x)= 6$.  Then $log_3(x^4)= 6$ and $x^4= 3^6$ so that $x= 3^{6/4}= 3^{3/2}$.